# self is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

```
class ObjectCreateMixin:
    model_form = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.model_form()
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': form})
```

**self.model_form is not callable.**

Я так понимаю, что нельзя вызвать метод у переменной со значением None. Как быть, если нужно вызвать метод, но исходное значение None  ?

Comment: Вызывайте только, если не равно None.

Comment: в любом случае, vscode подчеркивает строку self.model_form()

Comment: А как метод будет появляться там? В `__init__`? Если да, то объявление его как `None` не имеет смысла

Comment: без __init__ разве self будет работать ?

Comment: form = self.model_form() : если убрать скобки, то всё ок

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать метод у переменной со значением  `None` можно. Нельзя вызвать переменную None как метод¹. А именно это и происходит в коде

```
form = None()
```

Исправить код или дать совет невозможно,  потому что непонятно, что должно происходить.

¹ Но если None переопределить, то можно. Но так делать нельзя.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62232846/how-to-make-none-callable